# ASP.NET - Using json file to store CRUD operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to ASP.NET Core MVC and have created a Web API by following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api).

Everything works fine but the data for the CRUD operations is stored in memory, and I am being asked to have the data stored in a json file instead.

Can anybody give me some advice on how to do it, or point me to a quick tutorial that explains how to modify the context/repository to do this? I am used to Entity Framework/SQL server transactions and I know this is a lot simpler, but I have never done it before and need some guidance. :) I have found some related questions but they seem much more complicated than what I am trying to do.

My code matches exactly what is in the URL but I will be happy to post parts of it if it is helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Check this out. 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/858292/create-a-json-file-with-C-Sharp/
or 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786411/c-sharp-save-object-to-json-file or
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297574/easy-way-to-write-data-to-local-json-file

Comment: Are you sure that you want to add JSON objects in file - like plain text file? If you have file you would need to load entire file just to add/remove single object and then save it again. It just looks very strange requirement.

Comment: Maybe of-topic, but if you want example with SQL database you can find it here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1106622/Building-REST-services-with-ASP-NET-Core-Web-API-a

Comment: Thank you, Jovan. Yes, this is quick test project to familiarize myself with Bluemix and I was asked to store the data in a plain text file using json.